# Como acessar atributo de uma classe dentro de outra classe no Django?

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando simular um sistema de locação de veículos usando Django e me deparei com a seguinte dúvida:

como implementar a fatura? da forma como estou tentando fazer precisaria ter acesso aos atributos das classes Vehicle e Rental dentro da classe de Invoice, isso é possível?

segue o código

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    price_per_day = models.FloatField()

class Rental(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def time_diff(self):
        delta = self.end - self.start
        return delta.total_seconds() / 3600 // 24 # calculando a quantidade de dias da locação

class Invoice(models.Model):
    rental = models.ForeignKey(Rental, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # agora não sei como acessar o valor da diária do veículo e a quantidade de diárias da locação
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para ter acesso aos atributos das classes Vehicle e Rental na classe Invoice, você pode usar o relacionamento de chave estrangeira que você criou entre as classes.

Por exemplo, se você quer acessar o atributo price_per_day do veículo, basta fazer:

```
vehicle_price_per_day = self.rental.vehicle.price_per_day
```

E para acessar o atributo time_diff da classe Rental, basta fazer:

```
rental_time_diff = self.rental.time_diff
```

Você também pode usar o método related_name na definição da chave estrangeira para dar um nome mais amigável ao atributo que você usará para acessar o objeto relacionado. Por exemplo:

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='vehicle')
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def time_diff(self):
        delta = self.end - self.start
        return delta.total_seconds() / 3600 // 24 # calculando a quantidade de dias da locação

class Invoice(models.Model):
    rental = models.ForeignKey(Rental, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='rental')
    vehicle_price_per_day = self.rental.vehicle.price_per_day
    rental_time_diff = self.rental.time_diff
```

Assim, você pode acessar os atributos de Vehicle e Rental de forma mais clara e direta.

Comment: Eu consegui fazendo da seguinte forma:
vehicle_price_per_day = rental.vehicle.price_per_day
rental_time_diff = rental.time_diff